# Density and compactness of Boolean embeddings

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, boolean-algebras, compactness

Let **A** and **B** be Boolean algebras and $h:A\rightarrow B$ a
Boolean embedding.

- If every element of $B$ can be expressed both as a join
  of meets and as a meet of joins of elements in $h(A)$, then the embedding $h$
  is called dense.
- Assume also that $B$ is complete. If for all $S,T\subseteq A$
  with $\vee
  h(S)\leq\wedge h(T)$, there exist finite $S
  ′\subseteq S$ and $T
  ′\subseteq T$ such that $\vee S′\leq\wedge T′$
  , then the embedding $h$ is called compact.

---

Is there a way to write formally the definition of a dense Boolean embedding?
 Is there some intuition of what is a dense Boolean embedding? 
I know there is a relation between this definition of a compact embedding and the topological compactness, but why do you have to make this definition for embeddings, and not for Boolean algebras?
Is there any relation between a dense Boolean embedding and topological density?

Comment: Have you stated the compactness property properly? Why isn't that automatically true, taking $S'$ and $T'$ both as empty, which reduces it to $0\leq 1$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins looking at it, it seems to me that the correct one could be with $S\subseteq S'$ and $T\subseteq T'$, but I'm not sure, as this is the one that has been given to me.

Comment: No, that would be impossible if $S$ or $T$ is infinite.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Do you know where I can find a correct definition?

Comment: I think the right definition replaces your $\leq$ with $=$. That is, if $\bigvee h(S)=\bigwedge h(T)$ there there are finite subsets $S'\subset S$, $T'\subset T$ such that $\bigvee S'=\bigwedge T'$.

Comment: Or perhaps this is equivalent if you use $\geq$ in place of $\leq$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  what if I make a subset compact if every element is a compact element? In this sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_element

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I need the right definition to make this proposition true: Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra and $X_B$ its dual space. Then
$X_B$ is compact.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins sorry, if I'm been rude, maybe I was asking too much.

Comment: For the record, I asked my tutor and he make me realize that taking both sets as empty gives you $1\leq 0$, so it seems the definition is okey.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the dense embedding, perhaps this is helpful. Statement 1 can be taken as a definition of density, which makes the connection with topology by means of the lower-cone topology.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are Boolean algebras and
$h:A\to B$ is an embedding, meaning an injective homomorphism, an isomorphism of $A$ with a subalgebra of $B$. Then
the following are equivalent:

1. $h$ is dense in the sense that $h[A]$ is a dense subset of $B$,
   meaning that for every nonzero $b\in B$ there is nonzero $a\in A$ with
   $h(a)\leq b$.
2. $h$ is dense in the sense that every element of $B$ is the
   join of elements in $h[A]$.
3. $h$ is dense in the sense that every element of $B$ is the meet
   of elements in $h[A]$.

**Proof.** ($1\to 2$) Suppose that $h$ is dense in the sense of
(1), and consider any $b\in B$. Let $A_0=\{a\in A\mid h(a)\leq
b\}$. So $h[A_0]$ lies entirely below $b$, but the join of $h[A_0]$
must equal $b$, for otherwise there is some $c<b$ which is an upper
bound of $h[A_0]$. In this case, $b-c$ is nonzero and so has some
nonzero $h(a)\leq b-c$. So $a\in A_0$ and thus $h(a)\leq c$,
contradiction.

($2\to 3$) Assume $h$ is dense in the sense of (2), and consider
any $b\in B$. So $\neg b=\bigvee h[A_0]$ for some $A_0\subseteq A$.
By De Morgan reasoning it follows that $b=\bigwedge_{a\in A_0} \neg
h(a)$, and so $b$ is the meet of $h[\{\neg a\mid a\in A_0\}]$.

($3\to 1$) Assume $h$ is dense in the sense of (3), and consider
any nonzero $b\in B$. So $1\neq \neg b\in B$ and $\neg b$ is the
meet of $h[A_0]$ for some set $A_0\subseteq A$. So $\neg b\leq
h(a)$ for some $1\neq a\in A_0$, and consequently $0\neq h(\neg
a)\leq b$, as desired for (1). $\quad\Box$

The theorem shows that a dense embedding is one whose range is dense in the lower-cone topology on $B$, which answers your final question.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what is the lower-cone topology?

Comment: It is the topology (often on the nonzero elements $B-\{0\}$) whose basic open sets are the down sets $U_b=\{a\in B\mid a\leq b\}$.

Comment: Is this related with the Stone spaces? To me it seems like a weaker topology than the one endowed to Stone spaces, but probably I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe it is called the Alexandrov topology.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it the first time, what do you mean by "b-c" in the proof of the first implication?